# Downloading PDF as Blob with JS in IE9

Tags: javascript, pdf, internet-explorer-9, blob

I have a blob and want to download it. It works for Chrome, Firefox, IE10 and higher. The problem is IE9.

```
                    var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;  
                    var blob = new Blob([data], {type: "application/pdf"});
                    if (isIE) {
                        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, "Download.pdf");
                    } else {
                        var link = document.createElement('a');
                        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                        link.download = "Download.pdf";
                        link.id = "TEST";
                        $('body').append(link);
                        document.getElementById("TEST").click();
                    }
```

Where is the problem? The IE has 2.083 as maximal limit for chars in URL. Maybe this is critical. What alternatives do I have? I have to support IE9... Thanks.

Comment: Hi, did you ever figure this out.  I'm having the same issue where I'm using `msSaveBlob` and `createObjectUrl` that works in IE10, 11, Edge, FF, Safari, and Chrome, but I can't get it to work in IE9.  I can't seem to figure this out, or find a solution.

Comment: @JV3 you found any solution to work with IE9?

Answer (score 0):

As you can read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Blob) the Blob constructor is supported from IE version 10. You may want to use [PDF.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/).

Comment: PDF.js doesn't help me. I have to provide the file as binary, blob or something like that. A link which refers to the PDF is here no solution.